# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Set .env Laravel in Environment Properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

From my understand AWS Elastic Beanstalk has its own Environment Properties located in the Software Configuration panel, clicking on the Gear icon. In my Laravel's .env file I have information like my S3Bucket where I upload images, my Mail service and some others. Does this mean that I have to add each key and value pair from Laravel's .env file to the Environment Properties of AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: are you committing the `.env` file in your git repo ?, need to know so that I can help you out

Comment: No, I am not committing it for security reasons

Comment: so I think you may need to create all the env variables in the Software Configuration panel , https://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2015/05/29/laravel-5-configurations-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is **Yes**.

If you add environment variables within the Software Configuration, particularly, if you don't upload your .env file to the server, you'll have to reference these variables within your code.

For example, here is how you can reference this configuration within Elastic Beanstalk on the server and use the .env file locally:

Within config/app.php:

```
<?php

return [
    ...
    'env' => array_key_exists('APP_ENV', $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] : env('APP_ENV'),
    'debug' => array_key_exists('APP_DEBUG', $_SERVER) && $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] === 'false' ? false : env('APP_DEBUG'),

    ...
```

Note that I am doing 2 things here.

1. For the APP_ENV, since I will want 'production' on the server but 'dev' locally, here I want to, if available (i.e. only on the production server) use $_SERVER['APP_ENV'], otherwise use APP_ENV that I have defined in the .env file locally. Note that on Elastic Beanstalk, you just name the variable APP_ENV as well.
2. This is a bit of a gotcha. Any of the variables that you set within Elastic Beanstalk will come out as strings. So, of course, you will want to set APP_DEBUG to false when in production. However, this comes out to the string "false", which, if you test it "false" == true. Therefore, this will turn out to be true on the server. In order to get around this, I have used the code above to test if it APP_DEBUG is set to 'false' and if so, I set it to the boolean `false`

Now, this is only 2 examples within the config/app file. For you, you'll have to do the same for your S3 bucket and Mail servers within their respective config files.

I know that I'm replying super late, but I hope this helps someone else! :)

Comment: can we use this app running In console ?

Comment: @mssb, if you mean to run it on localhost, then, yes. note that the question in the ternary operator is seeing if a specific key exists within $_SERVER, if not, then it will get the information from the dot env file, which will be the case for working on the project on localhost

Comment: AWS EBS saves Environment Properties in $_SERVER and Laravel utilizes the [DotEnv][1] PHP library by Vance Lucas which loads environment variables from `.env` to `getenv()`, `$_ENV` and `$_SERVER` automatically. Which means that you can simply leave env() functions as they are and do not need to use array_key_exists() function.


  [1]: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv